# Pinning cordova platform and plugin versions

Tags: cordova, version, cordova-plugins

I have a cordova app that is going into production and I want to be able to pin down the exact version of the platforms and plugins we are using. This is so we can rebuild the app exactly as it is in this release at any time in the future.

For a normal node project you would use `npm shrinkwrap` for this. How is this done with cordova?

Comment: Can't you just remove the `~` or `^` from the version number in `package.json`?

Comment: Yes, and you probably should but make sure you set `save-prefix=''` either globally or using a .nmprc file otherwise it will mysteriously continue to use `~` or `^`. The default `save-prefix` is `~`. See here: https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/config#save-prefix

Answer (score 0):

In your terminal the following commands,

`cordova -v` will give you the exact version of Cordova and the platform versions

`cordova plugins` will give you the list of all the plugins with their versions

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you can just use `npm shrinkwrap` on your cordova project as you would any other npm based project. It will simply shrinkwrap your existing `package.json` file.

When installing plugins, cordova will use `npm-shrinkwrap.json` to download plugin data if it exists. If not, it will use `package.json`. If that doesn't exist it will use `config.xml`.